# Detect if a video is playing on Android

Tags: android, view

Can my app detect if a video is playing via a 3rd party player?

I want to hide a floating view (think Chatheads) when a video starts playing or becomes full screen.

Chatheads does this when a video is playing but how does it detect the playing video?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't monitor other apps behavior, more specifically, you can't capture or take snapshot of other apps but you can watch for special strings in logcat

Here's the logcat of the defaul `Movies` app of android:

```
05-21 12:30:03.709: ERROR/MediaPlayerService(803): error: -2147483648
05-21 12:30:03.709: ERROR/MediaPlayer(1778): Unable to to create media player
05-21 12:31:19.160: DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1852): getMetadata
05-21 12:31:19.370: WARN/MediaPlayer(1852): info/warning (3, 0)
05-21 12:31:19.400: INFO/MediaPlayer(1852): Info (3,0)
```

You should take care of player apps, too.